# Erro no select usando mysqli_query

Tags: php, mysql, sql-select, helper

Eu fiz um php para listar os quartos, mas estou a ter dificuldade em puder os listar, se alguém me poder ajudar, agradecia

```php
<?php
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","hotel");
$result = mysqli_query("SELECT descricao FROM quartos WHERE nome_quarto=Quarto Ibiza");
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
?>
<table class="table table-bordered">
    <tr>
        <th class="tg-031e" colspan="3"></th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="tg-031e"><img src="fotos/ibiza.jpg" height="300px"></td>
        <td class="tg-031e">
            <b><font size="5px" color="black">Descrição:</font></b>
            <p><font color="black" size="3px">
      <!-- Mostrar os dados que fui buscar ao select -->
            <?php
            echo $row['descricao'];
            ?>
            </p></font>
            <button type="submit" id="button1id" name="button1id"                 style="border:3px double black;" class="btn btn-primary" >Reservar</button> 
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

**Erros:**

> Warning: mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in F:\XAMPP\htdocs\Pap2\quartos.php on line 67
>
> Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, null given in F:\XAMPP\htdocs\Pap2\quartos.php on line 69

Comment: Por favor, coloque seu código aqui, removendo informações confidenciais que possam comprometer seu sistema. Apenas o código que contém o problema e partes relevantes. Assim poderemos te ajudar melhor.

Comment: já esta, pode ajudar pfv

Comment: Qual o problema? valores string precisam de aspas simples no sql.

Comment: Para colocar o código, da próxima vez, selecione todo o seu código e aperte no botão com o ícone "{}". Ou então, coloque quatro espaços antes de cada linha. Isso é importante especialmente com códigos começando com `<?`, pois isso é o que e engine de formatação de textos interpreta como o início de um texto invisível.

Answer (score 3):

O erro informado:

> Warning: mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in F:\XAMPP\htdocs\Pap2\quartos.php on line 67

É porque está faltando passar o *link* do MySQLi por parâmetro, antes inexistente nas funções MySQL:

Corrija passando a variável `$link` da seguinte forma:

```
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","hotel");
$result = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT descricao FROM quartos WHERE nome_quarto='Quarto Ibiza'");
```

E o segundo:

> Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, null given in F:\XAMPP\htdocs\Pap2\quartos.php on line 69

É porque faltou o parâmetro do tipo de *fetch*:

```
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
```

As opções de *fetch* são:

1. MYSQLI_NUM (trás em um array numérico `$row[0]`)
2. MYSQLI_ASSOC (trás em um array associativo `$row['descricao']`)
3. MYSQLI_BOTH (trás dos dois modos anteriores)

Também recomendo utilizar o MySQLi Orientado a Objetos, assim:

```
$link = new mysqli("localhost","root","","hotel");
$result = $link->query("SELECT descricao FROM quartos WHERE nome_quarto='Quarto Ibiza'");
$row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
```

Outro erro na sua consulta sql:

```
SELECT descricao FROM quartos WHERE nome_quarto=Quarto Ibiza
```

Tem um problema na clausura `WHERE` onde uma string deve ser passada dentro de aspas simples:

```
SELECT descricao FROM quartos WHERE nome_quarto='Quarto Ibiza'
```

Fica assim o código PHP:

```
$result = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT descricao FROM quartos WHERE nome_quarto='Quarto Ibiza'");
```

<sub>Tenho uma classe de conexão que ajuda bastante na hora de gerenciar a conexão: [ConnectionMSi](https://github.com/KaduAmaral/ConnectionMSi)</sub>

Comment: Da-me os seguintes erros :( Warning: mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in F:\XAMPP\htdocs\Pap2\quartos.php on line 67

Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, null given in F:\XAMPP\htdocs\Pap2\quartos.php on line 69

Answer (score 3):

> Warning: mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in
>   F:\XAMPP\htdocs\Pap2\quartos.php on line 67

Esse erro diz que a função espera dois argumentos e apenas um foi passado, logo, é
obrigatorio passar dois argumentos para a função `[mysqli_query()][1]` o primeiro a conexão e o segundo a query, é necessário passar os valores na query entre aspas simples quando esses valores são do tipo string.

```
$result = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT descricao FROM quartos WHERE nome_quarto='Quarto Ibiza'");
```

> Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result,
>   null given in F:\XAMPP\htdocs\Pap2\quartos.php on line 69

Normalmente esse erro indica que a sua consulta possui um erro de sintaxe(sql state 1054 mysql)

Comment: MUITO OBRIDADO, PROBLEMA RESOLVIDO ! OBRIGADO MESMO

Answer (score 2):

Acredito que seja isso o que você precisa:

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
    <tr>
        <th class="tg-031e" colspan="3"></th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="tg-031e"><img src="fotos/ibiza.jpg" height="300px"></td>
        <td class="tg-031e">
            <b><font size="5px" color="black">Descrição:</font></b>
            <p><font color="black" size="3px">
            <?php
                $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","hotel");
                $sql = "SELECT descricao FROM quartos WHERE nome_quarto='Quarto Ibiza'"
                $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

                while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                    echo $row['descricao'];
                }

                mysqli_close($conn);
            ?>
            </p></font>
            <button type="submit" id="button1id" name="button1id" style="border:3px double black;" class="btn btn-primary" >Reservar</button> 
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```