# Erro "Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given"

Tags: php, mysql, banco-de-dados, mysqli, select

Estou desenvolvendo uma API em PHP, cujo a mesma está hospedada na Hostinger. Porém, quando faço a consulta SQL em MySQLi, recebo o mesmo erro, não importa as mudanças que eu faça no código:

Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given android_connect/get_all_products.php on line 20

Quando mudo todo o código para MySQL, ele informa que o MySQL já está velho e pede para mim fazer em MySQLi.

Há alguma solução para este erro? Sem houver, e vocês puderem ajudar, eu agradeço.

**db_connect.php**

```
<?php

/**
 * Uma classe de conexão ao banco.
 */
class DB_CONNECT {

    // Construtores
function __construct() {
    // Realiza a conexão.
    $this->connect();
}

// Desconstrutor.
function __destruct() {
    // Encerra a conexão.
    $this->close();
}

  /**
 * Função para conectar-se ao banco.
 */
function connect() {
    //Importa as variaveis da conexão.
    require_once __DIR__ . '/db_config.php';

    // Conecta ao banco com as informações importadas.
    $con = mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD)or die(mysqli_error());

    // Seleciona o banco.
    $db = mysqli_select_db($con, DB_DATABASE)  or die(mysqli_error());

        // Retorna os cursores.
        return $con;
    }

    /**
     * Função que encerra a conexão,
     */
    function close() {
        // Fecha a conexao.
        mysql_close();
    }

}

?>
```

**get_all_product.php**

```
<?php
/*
 * Lista todos os itens que estão no banco.
 */

// Array para resposta do JSON
$response = array();


// Inclui as classes de conexão.
require_once __DIR__ . '/db_connect.php';

// Conecta-se ao banco.
$db = new DB_CONNECT();


// Pega os produtos da tabela AN_CAR
$result = "SELECT * FROM all_car";
$query = mysqli_query($con) or die (mysqli_error($con));

// Checa se há campos vazios
if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    // Se há campos preenchidos no banco, loopa todos os resultados e puxa. 

    $response["an_car"] = array();

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        // Array de todos os itens.
        $product = array();
        $product["id"] = $row["id"]; 
        $product["modelo"] = $row["modelo"];
        $product["marca"] = $row["marca"];
        $product["ano"] = $row["ano"];
        $product["motor"] = $row["motor"];
        $product["imagem"] = $row["imagem"];
        $product["preço"] = $row["preço"];



        array_push($response["all_car"], $product);
    }
    // Busca bem sucedida.
    $response["success"] = 1;

    // Mostra os resultados em JSON.
    echo json_encode($response);
} else {
    // Caso não encontre nada:
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "Não há itens.";

    // echo no users JSON
    echo json_encode($response);

}
?>
```

Comment: Possível duplicada de: [Erro no select usando mysqli_query](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/68124/91)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Seu código** contem vários erros, que usando *mysqli* ou não iriam ocorrer, entenda isto como uma critica construtiva:

Primeiro você pode chamar a o banco junto ao `mysqli_connect`:

```
function connect() {
     require_once __DIR__ . '/db_config.php';

     $con = mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_DATABASE) or die(mysqli_error());

     return $con;
}
```

Outra coisa em `connect` o `return $con` não vai retornar para o objeto construtor, mas sim para o "nada", veja:

```
function __construct() {
    // Realiza a conexão.
    $this->connect();
}
```

Você pode criar um método pra recuperar a conexão, a classe deve ficar assim:

```
<?php
class DB_CONNECT
{
    private $con;

    function __construct() {
        $this->connect();
    }

    function __destruct() {
        $this->close();
    }

    function connect()
    {
        if ($this->con) {
            return NULL;
        }

        require_once __DIR__ . '/db_config.php';
        $this->con = mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_DATABASE) or die(mysqli_error());
    }

    function getConnection()
    {
        return $this->con;
    }

    function close()
    {
        mysqli_close($this->con);
    }
}
```

> Eu não entendi a necessidade da classe, o propário mysqli pode ser escrito em oop, mas não vou entrar em detalhes.

Outra coisa muito importante, você esta tentando acessar `$con` fora da classe, mas ela esta no escopo da classe e não fora, o que torna impossível acessar **diretamente**, então com o método `getConnection` faça assim:

```
$db = new DB_CONNECT();
$con = $db->getConnection();
```

O outro problema é que aqui você não esta passando a query, apenas a conexão:

```
 $result = "SELECT * FROM all_car";
 $query = mysqli_query($con) or die (mysqli_error($con));
```

E você passou uma string para `mysql_fetch_array`, fora que você tem que usar mysqli em tudo, não adianta uma parte usar mysqli api e na outra a api antiga:

```
 while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
```

Faça assim:

```
$db = new DB_CONNECT();
$con = $db->getConnection();

$query = "SELECT * FROM all_car";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $query) or die(mysqli_error($con));


while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
}
```

Leia e faça exatamente como esta na documentação, ela serve pra ajudar:

- http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php
- http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/book.mysqli.php

Leia os exemplos, veja os comentários, siga o que a documentação diz desde os parâmetros até o que tipo de valor a função retorna, não somente para *mysqli*, mas para qualquer linguagem que fornece uma documentação.

Comment: Opa, Guilherme, agradeço a ajuda... 

Fiz as alterações conforme sugerido, porém o erro persiste. Quando coloco 

    $query = "SELECT * FROM all_car";
    $result = mysqli_query($con, $query) or die (mysqli_error($con)); 

o erro continua o mesmo. O que será que está errado?

Grato!

Comment: @WillCunha desculpe corrigi o código. Faltou o segundo parâmetro :)

Comment: Guilherme... cara, mesmo fazendo as alterações, ele continua retornando o mesmo erro. Será que é algum erro de configuração do PHP?

Comment: @WillCunha editei a resposta, por favor leia tudo novamente.

Comment: Guilherme, fiz as alterações sugeridas e, o erro permanece. Agradeço a ajuda cara!