# Estou tendo esse erro "Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli" no php ao consultar do banco de dados

Tags: php, mysqli

Olá estou tentando buscar os cursos do banco de dados.Para ver os cursos já cadastrados para não cadastrar no db denovo.Está me aparecendo esse erro:

```
  Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in 
  /storage/emulated/0/Documents/sistemaescolar/public/cad/curso.php on line 6
```

o código de conexão

```
$host="127.0.0.1";
$db="sistemaescolar";
$pswd="";
$user="root";
$connect  =  mysqli_connect ($host,$user,$pswd,$db);

if (mysqli_connect_errno()){
 echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
```

---

Fiz essa página abaixo para decidir que tipo vai se de cadatro,vindo de outro formulário:

```
include_once "class_pessoa.php";
if(isset($_POST["buttonSubmit"])){
    $escolha = filter_input(INPUT_POST,'opselect',FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
    if(filter_var($escolha,FILTER_VALIDATE_INT)){
        include_once "cad/conexao.php";
        $sql = "SELECT * from tipoCad where id=$escolha";
        $resultado = mysqli_query($connect,$sql);
        $dado= mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado);
        if($dado["nome"] =="Curso"){
            $curso = new Curso($dado["nome"]);
        }
        mysqli_close($connect);
    }                           
}
```

Na parte onde tem a classe Curso,tem um formulario para poder cadastrar no db

---

Em baixo está o codigo que está dando erro quando busca do banco:

```
    $sql = "select * from cursos";
    $resultado=mysqli_query($connect,$sql); 
    while($dados= mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado)){
        echo $dados['nome'];
    }
```

Comment: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/101172

Comment: `$sql = "SELECT * from tipoCad where id=$escolha";` coloca `$escolha` entre aspas simples ` $sql = "SELECT * from tipoCad where id='$escolha'";`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Se você der um `echo` nessa declaração SELECT

```
$escolha="qqcoisa";
$sql = "SELECT * from tipoCad where id=$escolha";
echo $sql;
```

o retorno vai ser `SELECT * from tipoCad where id=qqcoisa`

e essa SQL resulta em erro `Unknown column 'qqcoisa' in 'where clause'`

traduzindo `Coluna desconhecida 'qqcoisa' em 'where cláusula'`

O correto é colocar a variável  `$escolha` entre aspas simples

```
$escolha="qqcoisa";
$sql = "SELECT * from tipoCad where id='$escolha'";
echo $sql;
```

para que a sintaxe esteja correta, ou seja

```
 $sql = "SELECT * from tipoCad where id='$escolha'";
```

> o sql precisa usar `'` (aspas simples) quando é string, para números não precisa

```
$sql = "SELECT * from tipoCad where id=10";
```

> Caso exista uma coluna com nome `qqcoisa` no  `SELECT * from tipoCad where id=qqcoisa` vai retornar os registros cujo valores da coluna `id` são iguais aos valores da coluna `qqcoisa`