# Erro ao fazer select

Tags: php, mysql

> Warning: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given

eu já testei o `fetch_array`, `fetch_object`, não sei como tenho que fazer.

```
    function pegaId($nomeConteudo){
    $query = "select id from conteudo where nomeConteudo = {$nomeConteudo} ";
    $resultado = mysqli_query($this->conexao, $query);
    $value = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado);
    return $value;
}
```

Eu só quero receber o valor da ID, mas ele não me retorna. Como fazer?

--

A solução proposta não ajustou meu problema, apesar dele não retornar mais erros fazendo desta nova maneira:

```
    function pegaId($nomeConteudo){
    $query = "select id from conteudo where nomeConteudo = {$nomeConteudo} ";
    //$resultado = mysqli_query($this->conexao, $query);
    $resource = mysqli_query($this->conexao, $query);
    return $resource;
}
```

ele não me retorna nenhum valor aqui:

```
$id = $conteudo_fkid->pegaId($nomeConteudo);
echo $id;
```

Portanto ainda estou precisando fazer um select, e não estou conseguindo. Como proceder?

Comment: **André**, seja bem vindo. A pergunta que foi marcada, ela contém a resposta para seu problema. Faça o [tour] para saber como funciona o site, caso necessite de ajuda sobre as ferramentas do mesmo, acesse a [help].

Comment: Não resolveu meu problema, NoobSaibot

Comment: Creio que fiz confusão, veja: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/68124/

Comment: Eu ainda m encontro com dificuldade.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Motivo

O erro na consulta ocorre porque não está passando a variável entre *aspas* na *query*. E por ser uma *string*, é necessário.

---

#### Corrigindo

```
function pegaId($nomeConteudo){
    $query = "select id from conteudo where nomeConteudo = '{$nomeConteudo}'";
    //$resultado = mysqli_query($this->conexao, $query);
    $resource = mysqli_query($this->conexao, $query);
    return $resource;
}
```

---

#### Atenção

É muito importante saber como achar o problema. Então uma forma simples que poderia ser usada neste caso:

Simplesmente, seria adicionar `echo $query;` abaixo da linha que monta a *query*, ver a saída (que será a *query* pronta), copiar e fazer a consulta direto no banco.

Assim você terá certeza que sua *query* está correta, e poderá seguir analisando as próximas linhas do seu código.

Comment: Muito obrigado, resolvido o problema