# Problema com consulta utilizando SQL no PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Eu tenho o seguinte código:

```
$nomeConteudo = $_POST['tipoConteudo'];
echo $nomeConteudo;
$id = $conteudo_fkid->cataId($nomeConteudo);
echo $id;
```

Nele, a variável nomeConteudo recebe o valor de um formulário e logo em seguida o imprimi. Até ai funciona corretamente.

Acontece que preciso utilizar essa variável para comparação e fazer um `SELECT` na minha tabela `conteudo`, e retornar o valor do ID.

Este é o código do método:

```
function cataId($nomeConteudo){
  $query = "select id from conteudo where nomeConteudo = {$nomeConteudo}";
  $resource = mysqli_query($this->conexao, $query);
  return $resource;
}
```

Acontece que ele não me retorna nada no `echo $id`. Por outro lado, tem informações certas no banco para poder retornar.

Onde estou errando? Não visualizo nada errado na consulta.

Comment: Duplicata: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/326721/99718

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = "SELECT c.id id_conteudo FROM conteudo c WHERE nome = '$nomeConteudo'";

//Buscar
  $resource = mysqli_query($conexao, $query);

//Resultado
  if ($resource == null) {
  echo"Nenhum registro encontrado!";
  }else {
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resource)) {
        echo "ID: " . $row['c.id'];
        }
      }
```

não entendi bem esse seu problema, mas ver isso resolve! ele retorna o id de acordo com seu WHERE $nomeConteudo..

Answer (score 0):

Paulo. Provavelmente você está com problema na sua consulta.

Assumindo que o usuário digitou "Igreja" no formulário e fez um submit você terá o seguinte código dentro da própria página (ou em outra) para receber os dados e realizar a consulta pelo tipo;

```
if (isseet($_POST['tipoConteudo']) && $_POST['tipoConteudo'] != "") {
   $nomeConteudo = $_POST['tipoConteudo'];
   echo $nomeConteudo;
}
```

Se foi feito um `$_POST` e esse valor é diferente de vazio você irá realizar a consulta. Então vamos a função:

```
function requestID($nomeConteudo){
    $query = "SELECT id FROM conteudo WHERE nomeConteudo LIKE '%$nomeConteudo%'";
    $id = mysqli_query($this->connection, $query);

    return $id;
}
```

Caso você não tem certeza de que a palavra que o usuário digitou no formulário é igual a do banco de dados eu recomendo usar o operador `LIKE` do SQL. Caso contrário você pode usar usar um simples `=`, mas terá que garantir que as palavras são iguais.

Voltando ao script da página do formulário vamos fazer a chamada ao método. Para isso, vou usar um classe chamada Conteudo, onde se encontra o método `requestID`.

```
if (isseet($_POST['tipoConteudo']) && $_POST['tipoConteudo'] != "") {
   $nomeConteudo = $_POST['tipoConteudo'];
   echo $nomeConteudo;
   $Conteudo = new Conteudo();
   $id_consulta = $Conteudo->requestID($nomeConteudo);
   echo $id_consulta;
}
```

Tendo o método da consulta pronto o resto foi simples. Bastou instanciar a classe onde o método estava e passar a variável recebida pelo `$_POST` como parâmetro.

**Dica:**

Não trabalhe com Strings para realizar consulta (ao menos que seja necessário). O ideal, caso consiga, seria trabalhar com o ID, que traria mais performance para a consulta e uma maior garantia de "sucesso" na mesma.

**Veja mais:**

[Operador LIKE](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_like.asp)

[Guia prático de mysqli no PHP](http://blog.thiagobelem.net/guia-pratico-de-mysqli-no-php)